# Open vSwitch not working on Docker

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, docker, openvswitch

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and Docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:       17.12.1-ce
 API version:   1.35
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    7390fc6
 Built: Tue Feb 27 22:17:56 2018
 OS/Arch:       linux/amd64
Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      17.12.1-ce
  API version:  1.35 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.4
  Git commit:   7390fc6
  Built:        Tue Feb 27 22:16:28 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

Below is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
# Install the required packages
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install openvswitch-switch openvswitch-common
RUN apt-get -y install nano
RUN apt-get -y install iproute2
RUN apt-get -y install tcpdump
RUN apt-get -y install openssh-server
RUN apt-get -y install net-tools
RUN apt-get -y install iputils-ping
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

After that I'm doing:

```
$sudo docker build -t mhkabir/ovs-container:latest .
$sudo docker run -it mhkabir/ovs-container:latest bash
```

Inside container, when I try to check Open vSwitch it's showing the error:

```
root@60cf0a5b5cfd:/# ovs-vsctl show
ovs-vsctl: unix:/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock: database connection failed (No such file or directory)
```

Expecting your suggestions. thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Have you checked the log?

Answer (score 1):

this issue might be related to the directory `/var/run/openvswitch/` is missing, causing the `ovs-ctl` daemon to fail on startup , there is two potential workarounds :

1-create the directory `/var/run/openvswitch/` like `RUN mkdir /var/run/openvswitch/` in your docker file

2-manually execute the `/usr/share/openvswitch/scripts/ovs-ctl start` command

Answer (score -2):

Both ovs-vswitchd and ovsdb-server are running ?

Comment: After giving privileged to the container, it's working now! thanks

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.